# String substitution in awk bash shell

Tags: bash, shell, awk

```
cat filenames.txt
Document a.txt
Document b.txt
Document c.txt
```

Because I need to tar three files, so I use the command line

```
tar -cvzf backup.tar.gz "Document a.txt" "Document b.txt" "Document c.txt"
```

In order to do this:

```
cat filenames.txt | awk '{  how to add " "double quatation mark to file names}' | xargs tar -cvzf backup.tar.gz
```

Questions:
1.How to write code for awk {...}? Thanks.

2.When () is included in the filename, why tar command cannot work? How can I deal with special characters using tar?

Comment: What do you mean when `()` is included in filename it doesn't work ? Can you provide an example

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `xargs -I`:

```
cat filenames.txt | xargs -I {} tar -rvf backup.tar '{}'
gzip backup.tar
```

Comment: {} represents the string(like Document a.txt) and '{}' will have that string quoted, is that right?

Comment: It's wrong, it only tar the file Document a.txt and ignored the following lines.

Answer (score 3):

You can pass a file to the tar command using -T
It will then read the file and add all files inside that.

```
tar -cvzf backup.tar.gz -T filenames.txt
```

---

Example

```
$cat filenames.txt
Document a.txt
Document b.txt
Document c.txt

$tar -cvzf backup.tar.gz -T filenames.txt
Document a.txt
Document b.txt
Document c.txt

$tar -tvf backup.tar.gz
-rw-r--r-- me        4 2015-01-23 08:32 Document a.txt
-rw-r--r-- me        4 2015-01-23 08:32 Document b.txt
-rw-r--r-- me        4 2015-01-23 08:32 Document c.txt
```

---

Man page entry

> -T, --files-from=FILE
>   get names to extract or create from FILE

Answer (score 1):

You could also use [printf](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Printf.html), if you *need* to use awk and the fileformat is specified/generated like `STRING<SPACE>STRING.txt`.

```
awk '{ printf "\"%s %s\"\n", $1, $2 }' files.txt | xargs tar -cvzf backup.tgz
```

AWK is a great filter for processing generated rows and columns.

Since you don't need to filter the data, you could take the line as is.

```
$ awk '{ printf "%s\n", $0; }' files.txt | xargs -I {} tar -rvf backup.tar {}
Document A.txt
Document B.txt
```

Or without printf (the whole line)

```
$ awk '{ print; }' files.txt | xargs -I {} tar -rvf backup.tar {}
```

and compress it in the last step, gzip can't update compressed archives:

```
$ gzip backup.tar
```

Comment: This will break if a line in file is: `Document has c.txt`

Comment: You should not use  `cat` with programs that can read data itself: `awk 'some code' filenames.txt | xargs ...`

Comment: @anubhava Sure, i updated the answer, i already wrote if you *need* to use awk. Even if it makes no sense, the question is titled and tagged with awk.

Comment: Why don't you just use $0 instead of $1 and $2 ?

Comment: @JID because awk '{ printf "%s\n", $0; }' filenames.txt or awk '{ print; }' filenames.txt doesn't work with the pipe to gzip like you would expect. therfore i updated the answer.